# Generating random numbers from the Laplace distribution

Tags: r, statistics

I have been trying to generate random numbers from the double exponential(Laplace) distribution. I am at a point I can write the code anymore. Any help would be appreciated. The code below is what I have written.

```
rlaplace = function(u,a,b){
    u = c(runif(ns))
    for(i in 1:ns){
        if(u[i] <= 0.5){
            X = a+b*log(2*u)
        } else{
            X = a-b*log(2*(1-u))
        }
    }
    X
}
z1 = rlaplace(u,a,b)
```

Comment: Would the package `LaplacesDemon` help?

Comment: `rmutil::rlaplace` is now on CRAN.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [Probability distributions CRAN Task View](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Distributions.html), there are several packages that already implement the Laplace distribution, notably [distr](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/distr/index.html) and [Runuran](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Runuran/index.html).

So you should be able to install `distr`, for example, and do something like :

```
library(distr)
D <- DExp(rate = 1) 
r(D)(1)
```

Code taken from the examples of the `DExp-class` help page.

Comment: what exactly is the rate here? suppose for a laplace distribution, i have mean = 12000 and b = 700, how do i do it?

Comment: @Saurabh try `rmutil::rlaplace(10, 12000, 700)`

Answer (score 3):

Try this?

```
#Using pdf for a laplace RV:
#F(y) = 1/sqrt(2*sigma^2)*exp(sqrt(2)*abs(y-mu)/sigma)
rlaplace = function(n,mu,sigma){
  U = runif(n,0,1)
  #This will give negative value half of the time
  sign = ifelse(rbinom(n,1,.5)>.5,1,-1)     
  y = mu + sign*sigma/sqrt(2)*log(1-U)  
  y
}
```